# Didn't get GitServer on Synology DS2018+ working

Tags: git, nas, synology

I followed the instruction on [github](https://gist.github.com/walkerjeffd/374750c366605cd5123d) to setup a remote git server on my NAS. But what ever i do to clone a remote repository on the NAS locally i get

> **Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
>   Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights**

Any ideas how to proceed? Any logfiles to where i can look at? Even following this [instructions](http://blog.netgloo.com/2015/04/20/git-server-on-synology-ds115j-installation-and-configurations/) doesn't helped me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile i found the error. It was a mixture of not forwarding the port 22 on my router and a mistake in the sshd_config file which leads to ssh service error.